# Correct Centos Partition Setup for /var/www

Tags: centos, centos7, partitioning, diskspace

I am running Centos 7 and this is my df -h output.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  2.5G   48G   5% /
devtmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     32G   50M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               1014M  202M  813M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home  1.4T  434M  1.4T   1% /home
tmpfs                    6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                    6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1002
```

I have my web files stored under /var/www and need to allocate space for it. Looking at the above output I am assuming it is stored under the root directory. I also notice that the /home directory is where the majority of my space is and I would prefer to use most of that for my /var/www directory since this will contain my web files. I'm also guessing 32GB is plenty for the /home directory since that just contains the user created folders? I'm also unsure what the last two tmpfs file systems are being used for?

I have done a lot of research but could not find any solid answer on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. I've seen some suggestions about moving my /var/www files to the /home directory but I would prefer to keep them where there are. I also use SELinux so I don't want to have SELinux permission issues by moving them.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would prefer to make a symbolic link from `/var/www` to `/home/yourname/www`.

To do this:

```
mkdir /home/yourname/www
rsync -avz /var/www/* /home/yourname/www
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/yourname/www
rm -r /var/www
ln -s /home/yourname/www /var/www
```

You can also perform local mounting from some path in your `/home` dir to `/var/www` by defining it in your `/etc/fstab`

Hope this help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken though this would mess with the SELinux permissions as it is configured to run on /var/www correct? That is why I was trying to avoid that route. Also, maybe a dumb question, why would you symbolic link to a directory that you deleted?

Comment: You need to create a symlink named /var/www thats why you need to delete the existing directory first, after moving the data to your home dir

Answer (score 0):

A symbolic link would be a good option.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what that command would look like? In plain terms would it be symbolically linking from /home/myuser -> /var/www/vhosts/myuser?